# Help required to figure out the JTAG or UART pins

Tags: jtag

I have an old CDMA dongle lying around, so I thought to try to reverse engineer them, but am unable to figure out the UART or JTAG pins, I have attached a photo of the probable pins, can anyone help on how to confirm.
This is the link to the FCC website.
Thank you!
https://fccid.io/QISEC156/Internal-Photos/Internal-Photos-1419925

[image]

Comment: 1 - please post the picture of the other side too. 2 - do you see name on the micro-controller ?

Comment: What voltage readings do you get from them? Any connected to ground?